# Rundeck Jira integration giving issue not found for issue ID

Tags: jira, rundeck

I have Rundeck community edition 4.10.1. I want to include jira issue ID in my job execution. For that I installed plugins and the jira issue exists is showing up in workflow step. I configured

```
project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.login=username project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.password=password project.plugin.Notification.JIRA.url=https://jiratestuser.atlassian.net
```

under `project settings --> edit configuration file` in Rundeck UI. When I execute rundeck job, it is giving below error.

```
[Workflow result: , step failures: {1=JiraIssueNotFound: Issue key "HX-450".}, status: failed]
```

Below is my sample job definition:

```html
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='jira_issue'>
          <description>the jira issue to check</description>
        </option>
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>43dfd3a-e546-44e0-8d08-07e60dgdgd1a5</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>jira workflow test</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>true</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <step-plugin type='JIRA-Issue-Exists'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='issue-key' value='${option.jira_issue}' />
          </configuration>
        </step-plugin>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo This is test jira issue</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>43dfd3a-e546-44e0-8d08-07e60dgdgd1a5</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Can someone help me out with this?
Are there any problem with the plugins installed?

NOTE: Plugin version is `Jira Notification version1.0.1`.I installed plugins from Rundeck UI plugsins page.

Comment: Hi, do you see any clue after turning on the debug mode at the moment of executing the job? Also, could you test on Rundeck 5.0.1?

Comment: I tried from different account as well. Its giving same error. I need to upgrade Rundeck to 5.0.1 and should test it.

Comment: You can test the plugin on 5.0.1 without upgrading. Just launch the docker image or the war launcher.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k I got a chance to test jira workflow on community Rundeck v5.1.1
Its giving same error message -- `issue key not found`